# Get property from class object in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to get the values of three properties from a class which I am populating from a stored procedure but don't know how.

my viewModel :

```
public class SitesVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string SiteName { get; set; }

}
```

I populate a class in my Global.asax file like so:

```
string siteIpAddress = "67.46.255.255";  //HardCoded for testing
var site = context.Database.SqlQuery<SitesVM>("spSelect_SiteByIp", siteIpAddress);
```

The site is populated with the correct data, I can see it from the Locals debug screen,  but I don't know how to retrieve the ID and SiteName into a variables. I tried the following

```
var siteID = site.ID; //
```

but I get this build error:

'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do. Are you looking to get *one site* and assign its `ID` to `siteID`? If so, **which one?** Remember, `site` is a **list of `SitesVM`.**

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud, Users will be hitting the app from 20 different sites, all of which have set IP addresses which I have loaded in my database. I want to be able to default dropdown values with the site info. I realize that the sitesVM is being populated as an IEnumerable but I don't really understand why. I am passing in a parameter that will always only return one site. I don't declare site as an enumerable. The answers I got work, I just need a bit more education on classes and objects I guess. Thanks.

Comment: The reason you get back an enumerable is because the API has no knowledge that your query will only return a single result. If you want only one then do this, `context.Database.SqlQuery<SitesVM>("spSelect_SiteByIp", siteIpAddress).FirstOrDefault();` and you can leave the `siteID = site.ID;`.

Comment: @Michael Perrenoud, Thanks for the explanation, I have tried that but I get this build error:   'ArctecLogisticsWebFiles.Models.ViewModels.SitesVM' does not contain a definition for 'FirstOrDefault' and no extension method 'FirstOrDefault' accepting a first argument of type 'ArctecLogisticsWebFiles.Models.ViewModels.SitesVM' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Hi Alan, you need to reference System.Linq and add a line `using System.Linq` in your project, since `Single()` (as per my answer below) and `FirstOrDefault()` (per Michael's suggestion) are Linq extension methods

Comment: @Jon G, Thanks, I had already referenced LINQ and still get the same build error. Declaring site as a var and then setting the session variable to site.FirstOrDefault().ID seems to work so I'll move on from here, just would like to understand this better since Michael said it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

It's returning `IEnumerable<SitesVM>` rather than `SitesVM`

If you just want one result and you're sure there's only one, you could try:

```
site.Single().ID;
```

This will return the ID of the single member of the sequence, and will throw an exception if there are zero or >1 results

Answer (score 0):

The `SqlQuery()` function is not returning a `SitesVM` object, it is a returning an enumeration of such objects (an `IEnumerable`). There may be zero or more rows in the query result.

Use the [`First()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the first returned row. Note that this will throw an `InvalidOperationException` if the query returns no rows (the enumeration is empty).